# Menus en script de Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-menu

Estoy empezando en este mundo de los scripts de Google Sheets.

He visto como crear menús y submenús que aparecen en la hoja pero, aunque seguro será fácil, no he encontrado forma de hacer entradas activas e inactivas.

¿Qué función me permite activar o inactivar una opción de menú?

Answer (score 0):

La documentación de Google Apps Script no maneja los conceptos de "activar" ni de "desactivar" menús. Lo que maneja es crear un menú, agregar elementos al menú y agregar el menú a la interfaz de usuario para quitar un elemento de menú, debe agregarse un nuevo menú con el mismo nombre.

Referencia

- [Custom menus in G Suite](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)